# Node js / javascript: how to process streams sequentially with pipe and async/await when parsing csv and calling webservices with got?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, async-await, sequential

I'm trying to parse a csv file. For each line I need to call services using got.

I would like to process each line sequentially because there may be many lines and if everything runs in parallel i'll overload the service.

This is a simplified version of my current code:

package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "csv": "^6.0.5",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "got": "^12.1.0"
  }
}
```

services/service.js

```
import got from 'got';


export class Service{
    /**
     * @description HTTP GET /api/v2/findings
     * */
     static async GetService1 () {
        let response = await got("https://google.com");
        return response;
    }
    static async GetService2 () {
        let response = await got("https://google.com");
        return response;
    }
}
```

index.js

```
// Import the package
import * as csv from 'csv';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import {Service} from './services/service.js';

console.log("start");
let inStream;
inStream = fs.createReadStream(
  "test.csv");
inStream
  .pipe(csv.parse({
      delimiter: ';'
  }))
  .pipe(
    csv.transform(
      { parallel: 1 }, 
      (record) => {
        let col1 = record[0];
        (async () => {
          let response1, response2;
          response1 = await Service.GetService1()
          console.log("line %d, after call 1", col1)
          response2 = await Service.GetService2()
          console.log("line %d, after call 2", col1)
        })();
        console.log("line %d, after async", col1)
      }))

console.log("end")
```

test.csv

```
1;"muti-line
comment 1"
2;"muti-line
comment 2"
3;"muti-line
comment 3"
```

That code displays:

```
start
end
line 1, after async
line 2, after async
line 3, after async
line 2, after call 1
line 1, after call 1
line 3, after call 1
line 3, after call 2
line 1, after call 2
line 2, after call 2
```

We can see that there are several problems:

1. In the transform anonymous function, the main thread continues after the async block even if all the processing is not finished (message "after async" appears before "after call 1")
2. the lines are processed in parallel even though the parallel option for the transformer is 1 : we can see that because all "after call 1" messages appear before all the "after call 2"

What I would like to obtain is:

```
start
line 1, after call 1
line 1, after call 2
line 1, after async
line 2, after call 1
line 2, after call 2
line 2, after async
line 3, after call 1
line 3, after call 2
line 3, after async
end
```

problem 1) is a generic question regarding async/await in node. problem 2 is probably specifically related to the csv library or how the stream pipes work.

Any suggestion to have everything work sequentially? Ideally I would love to be able to configure a given level of parallelism, but I could live with full sequential execution.

I'm open to other libraries / implementations (for csv parsing beware of the muti-lines fields). Preferably with async/await rather then promises as it seems to be the more up to date syntax but if it can only be done with Promises why not...

Thanks!

Comment: If you want each line to be processed sequentially, why use async ?

Comment: because i'm calling the services with got library and I don't think that it can/should be done synchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your ReadableStream as an AsyncIterator, you can use a `for await ... of` loop. This will allow you to `await` your async action:

```
let inStream;
inStream = fs.createReadStream(
  "test.csv");

const readable = inStream
  .pipe(csv.parse({
      delimiter: ';'
  }));

let i = 0;
for await (const record of readable) {
  let col1 = record[0];
  let response1, response2;
  response1 = await Service.GetService1()
  console.log("line %d, after call 1", col1)
  response2 = await Service.GetService2()
  console.log("line %d, after call 2", col1)
}
console.log("end");
```

---

> the lines are processed in parallel even though the parallel option for the transformer is 1

In your original code, you get 1 line of CSV data, you start an async action, get the `"line %d, after async"` log, then get another line. Only one line is ever parsed at once by the CSV library. It's just that rather than "execute an async action and wait for it to finish", you tell it "execute an async action, then continue on without waiting".

---

> Preferably with async/await rather then promises

Async/await *are* using promises, they're just a different syntax.

`for await ... of` is a type of loop that takes an AsyncIterator, which is an object (for example, instances of ReadableStream) that can return multiple Promises and (technically optionally) say they're 'done' and to stop the loop.

By repeatedly getting a Promise, resolving it to a value (one line of CSV data) and `await`-ing in between, you can handle the stream line-by-line in a way that's shorter than when using `pipe()` or `on('...')` event-based functions. When the stream is exhausted, the `for await ... of` loop is told the iterator is 'done' and the next line, `console.log("end");` executes.